# Install pip package as www-data user

Tags: python, linux, pip, permissions

I'm unsuccessfully trying to install a python module with sudo and with the user www-data . I'm in /var/www/html/folder performing this action. below is the code I use and the error I get. I state that I already have permission to execute files in this folder as I have activated it. the error is only for PIP. Thanks in advice.

command used: `sudo -H -u www-data pip install --user package_name`

error:

`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/.local' Check the permissions.`

I also receive this warning:

`WARNING: The directory '/var/www/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.`

but the folders in question (.local and .cache/pip) do not exist in that path!

I tried to do `sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/.cache/pip`
but the path doesn't exists!

Answer (score 0):

Make director.local and .cache in /var/www

`sudo mkdir /var/www/.local`

`sudo mkdir /var/www/.cache`

Change its ownership to www-data
`sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/.local`

`sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/.cache`

Now install module using pip as www-data
`sudo -H -u www-data pip install package_name`